Is there an equivalent "local" framework to Azure Functions for .Net/C#
I like Microsoft's Azure Functions framework. What I don't like (on principle) is attaching myself to a specific vendor (lock-in). I know I can run the function host locally and that it is open-source. But outside development, running production on your own servers is totally unsupported (but possible https://dev.to/gjcampbell/running-azure-functions-in-iis-32a).
Is there a software framework that does the equivalent, without being at least somewhat dependent on Azure (but possibly capable of integrating with its services). That has the simple HttpTriggers en TimerTriggers and such. In short, is event driven.
I have spotted openfaas. but though it supports C# functions its architecture and setup are not direct equivalents it seems and at first glance more complex to setup.
